# What is the definition of a geometric progression?

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology, definition

If the first term in our geometric progression (GP) is $k$, and the common ratio is 0, then our sequence is $\{k, 0, 0, 0, 0,\ldots\}$. Is there anything wrong with this statement?

So, is $\{0, 0, 0,\ldots\}$ a GP?

I have googled for a definition of GP, but wikipedia (which I am skeptical about) is the only link with a definition. (uncited)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Wikipedia: [Geometric Progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) ***Note the very last line.***

> In mathematics, a geometric progression, also known as a geometric sequence, is a sequence of numbers where each term after the first is found by multiplying the previous one by a fixed, non-zero number called the common ratio. ... The sum of the terms of a geometric progression, or of an initial segment of a geometric progression, is known as a geometric series.
>
> Thus, the general form of a geometric sequence is
>
> $$a,\, ar,\, ar^2,\ ar^3,\ ar^4,\ \ldots$$
>
> and that of a geometric series is
>
> $$a + ar + ar^2 + ar^3 + ar^4 + \cdots$$
>
> **where $r \neq 0$ is the common ratio** and $a$ is a scale factor, equal to the sequence's start value. [bold face mine]

*Hence, to answer your question*, **NO**, in a geometric progression, the common ratio $r$ *cannot be zero.*

---

See also: [Encyclopedia of Mathematics: Geometric Progression](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Geometric_progression)

> A sequence of numbers each one of which is equal to the preceding one multiplied by a number $q\neq 0$ ...

There's an additional qualification there that $q \;\;\text{or r} \;\;\neq 1$.