# Is the same term geometric or arithmetic?

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology

Is a series with the same number for every term a geometric or arithmetic series?

Comment: Isn't it both? The common difference is $0$ and the common ratio is $1$!

Comment: Or is it neither?

Comment: Well, @ellieff1493, whether it's "both" or "neither" is really just going to depend on the precise definition of arithmetic or geometric progression that you use.

Comment: @ellieff1493 Why is it neither? I know you can't employ the formula for the sum of terms of geometric series $S(n)=a(1-r^n)/(1-r)$ if $r=1$ but that does not mean a sequence like $1,1,1,1,...$ is not geometric!

Comment: And an explanation I found is that arithmetic are linear but geometric aren't

Comment: you use the word series rather than sequence, do you meant to say Case A: $a_1=1$, $a_1+a_2=1$, $a_1+a_2+a_3=1$ , $\ldots$. or Case B: $a_1=1, a_2=1, a_3=1, \ldots$?

Comment: Case b, I worded it poorly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's both, and that doesn't tell you anything you didn't already know about constant sequences.

Comment: Except when the series is exactly $0$, the common ratio does not exist.

Comment: @FrenzyLi Think of geometric series in terms of multiplication, instead of division. You'll see that $0,0,0,\dots$ is not very diferent than $2,2,2,\dots$.

Comment: You may consider including your comment in the body of the answer, because [it is not a trivial observation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321287/what-is-the-definition-of-a-geometric-progression).